# NLTK Wordnet getting the list of Synsets in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nltk, wordnet

I'm creating lemmas and synsets for Italian language using NLTK Wordnet, it looks okay:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

ll=wn.synsets('carta', lang='ita')
ll 

[Synset('card.n.01'),
 Synset('map.n.01'),
 Synset('sheet.n.02'),
 Synset('document.n.01'),
 Synset('charter.n.01'),
 Synset('menu.n.01'),
 Synset('paper.n.01')]

hypernyms[0].lemmas(lang="ita")
[Lemma('paper.n.01.carta')]
```

But I'm trying to receive after the last operation not only one list value but list with all values for all synsets I have in `ll`.

Used couple approaches but they don't work:

First one, still using NLTK:

```
lemmas = wn.lemmas(ll, lang="ita")
'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

And another with a loop:

```
i = iter(list(range(6)))

    for i in ll[i].lemmas(lang='ita'):
        print(ll[i].lemmas(lang='ita'))
list indices must be integers or slices, not list_iterator
```

How this could be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension

```
[synset.lemmas(lang='ita') for synset in ll]
```

output

```
[[Lemma('card.n.01.carta')],
 [Lemma('map.n.01.carta'),
  Lemma('map.n.01.carta_geografica'),
  Lemma('map.n.01.cartina'),
  Lemma('map.n.01.mappa')],
 [Lemma('sheet.n.02.carta'), Lemma('sheet.n.02.foglio')],
 [Lemma('document.n.01.atto'),
  Lemma('document.n.01.carta'),
  Lemma('document.n.01.documento'),
  Lemma('document.n.01.incartamento'),
  Lemma('document.n.01.scrittura')],
 [Lemma('charter.n.01.carta'), Lemma('charter.n.01.statuto')],
 [Lemma('menu.n.01.carta'), Lemma('menu.n.01.menu'), Lemma('menu.n.01.menù')],
 [Lemma('paper.n.01.carta')]]
```